# Bootstrap 3: How to align everything within desired area

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am layout basic design and using Bootstrap 3. So far I am loving it, but time to time I encounter issues.

Below code is a piece of my header - I am trying to arrange all elements within a given column to be aligned.

However, all of the encapsulated (within column) elements mis-aligned. How can I make them all to be aligned vertically?

Piece of Code:

```
<div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 pull-right">
   <a href="#"><span class="label label-danger">Buy: 42</span></a>
   <a href="#"><span class="label label-success">Sell: 84</span></a>

   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
   </button>

   <form class="navbar-form pull-right" role="search" style="width:50%">
     <div class="input-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
         <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            </button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `navbar-form` has padding. If you remove that everything should line up.

Another option, if you want this inside of a navbar, I would do something like..

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#"><span class="label label-danger">Buy: 42</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="label label-success">Sell: 84</span></a></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></button></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

This will act more responsively.

Demo of both examples: http://bootply.com/96394

Answer (score 1):

1. The search bar is aligning right because you're applying the "pull-right" class to the form. If you remove that class, it will be aligned left. Under the "Buy" and "Sell" elements.
2. If that's not actually a navbar (which it doesn't seem like it is), you should probably just use the plain old form instead of the navbar form. See [input groups in the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups). You can add the search [glyphicon](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons) if you want similar styling.

Comment: Sorry, I want it to be aligned vertically -- my bad.

Comment: Then the best way is probably to use Bootstrap's [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). Another option would be to float everything left.

My second comment still applies; use a normal input instead of the navbar one unless you're creating a navbar.